# using replace with to replace link with other link at runtime using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, replace

I have got two links :

```
<li><a href="/newproducts" id="quiklinks_02">New products</a>

<a href="/c/13/latest-products"/>
```

I want to replace the href="/c/13/latest-products" with href="/newproducts" , how can i acheive this using replace with.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `replaceWith` if you want to just change the `href`. You can simply use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("a[href='/c/13/latest-products']").attr("href", $("#quiklinks_02").attr("href"));
```

You may be able to improve the first selector as I get the impression the example in your question is not your full code!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li a:eq(1)').attr('href',$('li a:eq(0)').attr('href'));
```